# How to get the version of mongodb by mongo-go-driver

Tags: mongodb, version, mongo-go-driver

I need to get the version of mongodb.
The project is written in golang using mongo-go-driver.

Answer (score 1):

The following code prints the version from the `serverStatus` database command.

```
var commandResult bson.M
command := bson.D{{ "serverStatus", 1 }}
err := client.Database("test").RunCommand(context.TODO(), command).Decode(&commandResult);

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}       

fmt.Printf("Db version: %+v\n", commandResult["version"]) // e.g., `4.2.8`
```

Answer (score 0):

The version is returned as part of the [buildInfo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/buildInfo/#buildinfo) admin command.

Connect to the admin database and use the [RunCommand](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Database.RunCommand) function to run the buildInfo command.

The `version` field in the result will contain the MongoDB server version.